# {{ $data or 'Default' }} is not working in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to use convenient shortcut in blade file, which shows error on the screen.

```
@extends('layout/master')
@section('content2')
<h1>
    {{date('d m y')}}   <br>
    @{{date('d m y')}}  <br>
    {{ isset($data) ? $data : 'Not' }}
    {{ $data or 'Default' }}
</h1>
@stop
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers. EDIT your question and add the error message.

Comment: What are you expecting to do

Comment: Why do you expect it to work? It's been removed from Laravel since version 5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to use in that case is [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce), which was introduced in PHP7.

> The expression (expr1) ?? (expr2) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 is NULL, and expr1 otherwise.
>   In particular, this operator does not emit a notice if the left-hand side value does not exist, just like isset(). This is especially useful on array keys.

Therefore you can use it like this:

```html
{{ $data ?? 'Default' }}
```